# My closure example doesn't work as I tought

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to figure out closures and created this simple example where you call the function greet with a name and after the first call the greeting should contain the previous given names.

So if you call greet('Andrew') and greet('Joseph') I expect to see on the console:

```
Hello Andrew
Hello Andrew, Joseph
```

Here's my code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVpBdy

```
let greet = function(name) {
    let greeting = 'Hello ';

    let updateGreet = function() {
      greeting = greeting + ', ' + name; 
    }

    let printGreet = function() {
      console.log(greeting + name);
      updateGreet();
    }

    return printGreet();
} 

greet('Andrew');
greet('Joseph');
```

The result I'm seeing is:

```
Hello Andrew
Hello Joseph
```

It appears greeting is being re-initialized every time I call greet() and I have no idea why.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: *"t appears greeting is being re-initialized every time I call greet() and I have no idea why."* Because you are telling it to. Every time a function is called, every line in its body is executed, which means creating a new variable `greeting` and new functions `updateGreet` and `printGreet`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current `greet` can be called to *create* a self-contained object - the *object* then stores the names. Every time you call `greet` currently, you're creating a separate `greeting` variable, encapsulated in a different object.

Easiest method would be to execute the function immediately so that all calls to `greet` will reference the same object.

You should also pass the `name` variable to `updateGreet`:

```js
const greet = (() => {
  let greeting = 'Hello';
  const updateGreet = function(name) {
    greeting = greeting + ', ' + name;
  }
  const printGreet = function(name) {
    console.log(greeting + ', ' + name);
    updateGreet(name);
  }
  return printGreet;
})();

greet('Andrew');
greet('Joseph');
greet('Bob');
```

Also make sure to use `const` whenever you're declaring a variable whose reference isn't going to change - it makes code easier to understand (both for you and for others).

Answer (score 0):

The variable `greeting` is bound to the scope of the function `greet`. Thus, every time you call `greet()`, the greeting variable is re-initialized using `let greeting = 'Hello ';`

To achieve your desired result, you can move the `let greeting = 'Hello '` outside the scope of `greet`, so that it remains.

```js
let greeting = 'Hello ';
let greet = function(name) {
    let updateGreet = function() {
      greeting = greeting + ', ' + name; 
    }

    let printGreet = function() {
      console.log(greeting + name);
      updateGreet();
    }

    return printGreet();
} 

greet('Andrew');
greet('Joseph');
```

Comment: You are making `greeting` global here

Comment: @RahulDesai: The desired impact _is_ global

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This does not explain how closure work, which is the goal here

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you do not care too much about getting that specific output, but you care about understanding the concept. Therefore i have simplified your example to this:

```
function greet (greeting) {

    return function person (name) {
        console.log(greeting + ',' + name)
    }

}

helloGreeting = greet('hello')

helloGreeting('andrew') // 'hello, andrew'
helloGreeting('joseph') // 'hello, joseph'
```

What happens here is that when you first call `greet` the function returns a closure -- `person`. A closure, is a function declared inside another function, and by virtue of being declared inside that function it has access to anything defined within the outer function.

So after you call `greet('hello')` js returns the `person` function, and this function has access to the `greeting` variable previously defined.

In particular, the execution context of the function person contains the variable greeting. You can think of the execution context as a box, and every time you run `person` by calling `helloGreeting` this box also contains the variable `greeting` defined as hello.

the beauty of this is that now you can also defined other greetings.

```
niceToMeetYouGreeting = greet('niceToMeetYou')
yoGreeting = greet('Yo')
```

this makes for really reusable code that can be constructed by composing multiple functions. A really good way of making your code modular!

Answer (score 0):

Closure is not observed because the `greet` function does not return a function but rather a function call which results in the value `undefined`. To observe closure, the outer function can be called as an IIFE and should return the function `printGreet` which gets stored in the variable `greet`. Now `greet` has a reference to the `printGreet` function which still maintains a connection to it's lexical environment.

```js
let greet = (function() {
  let greeting = 'Hello ';

  let updateGreet = function(name) {
    greeting = greeting + ', ' + name; 
  }

  let printGreet = function(name) {
    console.log(greeting + ', '+ name);
    updateGreet(name);
  }

  return printGreet;
}());

greet('Andrew');
greet('Joseph');
```